# How do i convert c++ 'int' to javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am about to translate my C++ code to javascript on my *c++ web-based ide with source content tracer* I want the converted variable to not just be a `var` but an something like an int so that it can detect if the assigned value is valid or not

UPDATE:Knowing that int and float in javascript cannot be distinguish using `typeof` Then what is the best way to detect if the c++ float variable has a valid float value? same as detecting if a c++ int variable has a valid int value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `int` in JavaScript, only `number`.  Also, variables in JavaScript are not strongly typed.  The type is defined by the value assigned.

If you want to determine if the assigned value is a number, you can use `typeof exampleVar === 'number'`.

See also:

- [MDN `typeof` documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof)
- [MDN "Values, variables, and literals"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals)

Comment: using that, i wont distinguish an int from a float?

Comment: @fireflieslive there is no difference between int and float in JS.

Comment: @fireflieslive Perhaps you can try something like `parseInt(number, 10) === number`

Comment: If you are thinking of identifying and differentiating a float from int using javascript, can't you convert the variable into a string and check for the presense of "." or "+" or "-" in the string? Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript and C++ are very different beasts. Traditionally, variables in JavaScript are not strongly typed, which is why you can do this:

```
var x = 5; // x is a number
x = 'foo'; // now x is a string
x = {};    // now an object
x = [];    // now an array (which is also an object)
x = false; // etc., etc.
```

In C++, if you declared `x` as an `int` then the compiler wouldn't allow that code. There is no such check in JavaScript.

**If you really want type safety**, there is something *approaching* it if you compile your JavaScript using something like [Google's Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/). This involves annotating your JavaScript code with specially-formatted comments that enable the compiler to verify consistent typing in your code *to some extent*. It is far from perfect, and I wouldn't recommend it for anything other than a Very Serious™ project due to the significant overhead it imposes on development.